# TCL print tab character on terminal window

Tags: tcl

When trying to print a tab character (ASCII hex 0x09) from tcl it gets converted to spaces (ASCII hex 0x20). How do I avoid this behavior and get the tab character itself on the terminal window?

```
% puts "aa\t\tbb"
aa              bb
```

Space between `aa` and `bb` wrongly filled with 0x20 characters and not two 0x09 characters.

```
% puts "aa\u0009\u0009bb\n"
aa              bb
```

Same result. Strings though do seem to contain 0x09:

```
% set a "aa\t\tbb"
aa              bb
% string length $a
6
```

so this is only a `puts` behavior.

Background: 
I want the tab character to be present so I can copy-paste a list of numbers from the terminal into a spreadsheet, where the numbers end up in different spreadsheet cells.

Answer (score 0):

Tcl itself will be writing real tabs — the `puts` command doesn't translate tabs to anything else in any mode that I'm aware of — but it is up to the terminal to determine what to do with them. It seems that your terminal is replacing the tabs with spaces; *it's happening after the character has left Tcl's control,* and so there's not much it can do.

You can verify that what I say is true by redirecting the output of your code to a file and looking directly in that with a tool like a text editor or `od -c` (if you've got a set of POSIX tools). The tab will be there. Tcl does not change behaviour significantly between writing to a file and writing to a terminal; that would be a horrible bug if it was true.

(It's technically possible that there is an output filter on the `stdout` channel that is doing the transform, but that's pretty unlikely! What's more, it'd be even more unlikely for it to be there without you knowing it.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Problem seem to be the terminal: `echo -e "xx\t\tyy" | hexdump` lists the tab characters, but `echo -e "xx\t\tyy"` prints spaces on the terminal. Tried various `stty` options but no luck.